# std::move with three parameters - iterator passed by copy

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, move

I am using the following std::move syntax:

```
std::move(values.begin(), values.end(), dest);
```

`dest` is a forward output iterator, and the destination container has at least `values.size()` items after `dest`

The problem is, I call this multiple times in a loop, but `dest` seems to be passed by copy, and thus the items `dest` is pointing to are overwritten each time, instead of being appended.

1. Where is the documentation for this syntax? I can only find the single parameter version on cppreference.
2. Is there any way to pass the dest iterator by reference, or to get its result as a return value, in order to avoid the "overwrite" behavior when calling the above function multiple times in a loop?

I know I could use `dest += values.size();` each time, but that's for the sake of better knowledge...

Thanks

Comment: You probably want `dest = std::move(values.begin(), values.end(), dest);`

Comment: Look for the one in algorithm: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move (Note that there is a cross-link at bottom to switch between the *algorithm* move, and *utility* move )

Answer (score 8):

`dest` iterator is returned from move algorithm. You can just use:

```
dest = std::move(values.begin(), values.end(), dest);
```

Here is link on this algorithm: [std::move (algorithm)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::move(values.begin(), values.end(), std::back_inserter(dest));
```